# Append to a JSON array in a JSON file on disk, every second using C++

Tags: c++, json

This is my first post here, so please bear with me.

I have searched high and low on the internet for an answer, but I've not been able to resolve my issue, so I have decided to write a post here.

I am trying to write(append) to a JSON array on file using C++ and JZON, at intervals of 1 write each second. The JSON file is initially written by a “Prepare” function. Another function is then called each second to a add an array to the JSON file and append an new object to the array every second.

I have tried many things, most of which resulted in all sorts of issues. My latest attempt gave me the best results and this is the code that I have included below. However, the approach I took is very inefficient as I am writing an entire array every second. This is having a massive hit on CPU utilisation as the array grows, but not so much on memory as I had first anticipated.

What I really would like to be able to do is to append to an existing array contained in a JSON file on disk, line by line, rather than having to clear the entire array from the JSON object and rewriting the entire file, each and every second.

I am hoping that some of the geniuses on this website will be able to point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my code:

```
//Create some object somewhere at the top of the cpp file
Jzon::Object jsonFlight;
Jzon::Array jsonFlightPath;
Jzon::Object jsonCoordinates;
int PrepareFlight(const char* jsonfilename) {
  //...SOME PREPARE FUNCTION STUFF GOES HERE...
  //Add the Flight Information to the jsonFlight root JSON Object
  jsonFlight.Add("Flight Number", flightnum);
  jsonFlight.Add("Origin", originicao);
  jsonFlight.Add("Destination", desticao);
  jsonFlight.Add("Pilot in Command", pic);
  //Write the jsonFlight object to a .json file on disk. Filename is passed in as a param    of the function.
  Jzon::FileWriter::WriteFile(jsonfilename, jsonFlight, Jzon::NoFormat);
  return 0;
}
int UpdateJSON_FlightPath(ACFT_PARAM* pS, const char* jsonfilename) {
  //Add the current returned coordinates to the jsonCoordinates jzon object
  jsonCoordinates.Add("altitude", pS-> altitude);
  jsonCoordinates.Add("latitude", pS-> latitude);
  jsonCoordinates.Add("longitude", pS-> longitude);
  //Add the Coordinates to the FlightPath then clear the coordinates.
  jsonFlightPath.Add(jsonCoordinates);
  jsonCoordinates.Clear();
  //Now add the entire flightpath array to the jsonFlight object.
  jsonFlight.Add("Flightpath", jsonFlightPath);
  //write the jsonFlight object to a JSON file on disk.
  Jzon::FileWriter::WriteFile(jsonfilename, jsonFlight, Jzon::NoFormat);
  //Remove the entire jsonFlighPath array from the jsonFlight object to avoid duplicaiton next time the function executes.
  jsonFlight.Remove("Flightpath");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't "append" to a JSON string.  Once you've closed the string (matching "[" with "]", eg) then you must start a new JSON string.

Comment: (You can, on the other hand, leave the file "open" -- write an initial "[", then append your first string.  To append the 2nd string first write a ",".  After the last string write "]".  Or use file update mode to change a closing "]" to ",", write the appended data, then another "]".)

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I was thinking, hence me actually writing the entire array to file every time I have to append to the array. I was just hoping that I was suffering from amateur programming symptoms and that I was missing something obvious. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't rewrite everything every time -- one of the techniques above (or several others) should work.  At worst you'd have to write some code to scan through afterwards and clean things up before you read the JSON.

Comment: is a single file approach mandatory? You could group your objects by page or batch and write a entire but smaller file.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can do "flat file" storage yourself.. but this is a symptom of needing a database. Something very light like SQLite, or mid-weight & open-source like MySQL, FireBird, or PostgreSQL.

But as to your question:

1) Leave the closing ] bracket off, and just keep the file open & appending -- but if you don't close the file correctly, it will be damaged & need repair to be readable.

2) Your current option -- writing a complete file each time -- isn't safe from data loss either, as the moment you "open to overwrite" you lose all data previously stored in the file. The workaround here, is to *rename* the old file as a backup before you start writing.

You should also make backup copies of your file, with the first option. (Say at daily intervals). Otherwise data loss is likely to occur eventually -- on Ctrl-C, power loss, program error or system crash.

Of course if you use any of SQLlite, MySQL, Firebird or PostgreSQL all the data-integrity problems will be handled for you.